# Bitmap.getPixel(x,y) returns different colors depending on device

Tags: java, android, colors, bitmap, device

I have tested my app on 4 different devices (Oneplus 5T, Oneplus 3T, Lenovo TB2-X30F and Huawei P9 Lite Mini).

I have drawn an image that should have the color `Color.rgb(150,50,0)`, but when i use `Bitmap.getPixel()` on the loaded bitmap the two Oneplus phones return the red-value as `151` and the other two return `150`.

I think that it might have something to do with the devices, but other than that i have no idea what is happening. I hope that someone will be able to enlighten me on what is going on and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

I also don't know how Stack Overflow works, so i'm sorry if i have asked about this the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, colors are device specific for Bitmap. Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/color-in-bitmaps

Comment: Okay, thank you! Would you then say that i should use another class rather than Bitmap to solve the problem? @AmanChhabra

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: @Prateek shall do